# How to grab multiple rows from a table with the same value for a foreign key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a table named Drivers set up like this:

```
ID    QuoteID   Name   Amount
1     1         jim    100
2     1         bob    200
```

It could be the case where there are 1 or many rows with different PK's (ID), but have the same foreign key (QuoteID).  In either case, I want to grab all the people with a given QuoteID and be able to manipulate the value under "Amount" for each one.

I'm working in MVC 4 using Razor.  Here is what I have so far in my controller:

```
long quoteID = model.Driver.QuoteID.Value;
var driversModel = db.Drivers.Single(g => g.QuoteID == quoteID);

//amt1 should be for jim and amt2 should be for bob
double amt1 = driversModel.Amount * 1.04;
double amt2 = driversModel.Amount * 1.05;
double total = amt1 + amt2;
```

Can someone give me a shove in the right direction?  Should I be using something other ".Single" to give me access to those amounts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Single()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.single.aspx) get's one row. Use `Where()` to get all the rows that satisfy the query.

```
IEnumerable<Drivers> driversModel = db.Drivers.Where(g => g.QuoteID == quoteID);

// SingleOrDefault - default value if that element is not found.
Driver jim = driversModel.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == "jim");
Driver bob = driversModel.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == "bob");

double jimsAmount = jim.Amount ?? 0;
double bobsAmount = jim.Amount ?? 0;

double amt1 = jimsAmount * 1.04;
double amt2 = bobsAmount * 1.05;
double total = amt1 + amt2;

// Project to a list of doubles.
List<double> amounts = driversModel.Select(x => x.Amount);

// Sum amount property on Driver.
double sum = driversModel.Sum(x => x.Amount);
```

Comment: Thanks for the great example.  In the case where I don't know how many people are there, I could just loop through the driversModel object, right?

Comment: @SantasNotReal exactly. You can use LINQ projection. See my updated answer.

Comment: @SantasNotReal yes, you can loop over the driversModel. You could also use `driversModel.Sum(x => x.Amount)` if you don't need the individual amounts.

Comment: @crashmstr I've updated my answer with your `Sum` suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

`var driversModel = db.Drivers.Where( d => d.QuoteID == quoteID )` returns all drivers records that have the specified `quoteID`

You would then need to join against wherever you get the amount multiplier, multiply with `.Amount` and `SUM` the results.